# What is the best way to create a custom picker for measurement selection in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am currently building an app which allows users to select their current weight and waist size. The list is long since, for example, the weight will start from 40kg up to 300kg, and each value will have a decimal point from .1 up to .9, e.g 40.0, 40.1, 40.2, 40.3, ... 40.9, 41.0, the whole numbers will be represented in a longer vertical line, while the decimal values in shorter vertical lines. So as you can imagine, the list is going to be really long. I have already implemented 2 ways: FlatList and Carousel using react-native-snap-carousel. They have their pros and cons, FlatList is much performant than the Carousel, but im having a hard time getting the value of the middle line. While the carousel performs poorly, i do have access to the current selected item. So my question here is: how do i implement this performance-wise and i have access with the currently selected item. Take Note also that i have implement FlatList's onViewableItemsChanged and it still doesn't achieve my goal

here is the screenshot of the UI:

[image: weight modal picker]

Answer (score 0):

**In short:**

You can check this library out: https://github.com/veizz/react-native-picker-scrollview

**In detail:**

There's a way to achieve this with some [Flatlist](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) props:

- `onScrollBeginDrag` & `onScrollEndDrag`: detect when user starts/stops scrolling
- `onMomentumScrollBegin`  & `onMomentumScrollBegin` : detect scroll speed and momentum
- `scrollTo` or `scrollToIndex` functions which requires Flatlist ref.
- `onScrollEvent` if needed.

---

**My opinion is,** (which'll be my approach)

First, set the **selectedItem** as you like.

Then, using those scroll props above to detect which **item(index)** it's scrolling to. **Select that item.** Then `scrollTo` to selected.

Any point where it exceeds the threshold, use `scrollTo` or `scrollToIndex` to the next/previous item.

This is my approach, if you have your own, I'll be glad to discuss.

Happy coding!

Comment: thanks for the response. i will try your suggestions!

Comment: i tried the react-native-picker-scrollview but it doesn't support horizontal layout

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't go through all the library. I think there's one thing left is to try manually customized it as I said above.